# Rest API with authentication token

Tags: java, android, rest, httpclient

I have an android application calling a Rest API with the authentication token, with the following code

```
private void apiCall(){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams param = new RequestParams();
    client.addHeader("IDENTITY_KEY",TOKEN);
    client.get(URL, param, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
             mTextMessage.setText(statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            mTextMessage.setText(statusCode+"");
        }
    });
}
```

the problem is when I run the application it returns 0, WHY? 
URL and TOKEN declared and initialized outside the method.

Comment: Please print the value of Throwable error in onFailure. It should contain more details on the issue you are having.

Comment: I think something wrong happened on my computer, perhaps fault on internet connection or something else, I restarted my computer and  problem has  been solved,  thank you for your response

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use the [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to do that.

Let's say your URL base is http://baseurl.com/api and you have to perform a GET request to /login passing the email and password. I am assuming that your API will return a User object as JSON.

Api.java

```
@GET("login")
Call<LoginResponse> verifyLogin(@Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String password);
```

Where you need to perform API call do the following

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://baseurl.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
Call<LoginResponse> responseCall = api.verifyLogin("email","password");
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<ProductResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ProductResponse> call, Response<ProductResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                //do whatever you need, 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ProductResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("error",t.getMessage().toString());

        }
    });
```

Note: LoginResponse is a POJO class. You have to make a POJO class to perform retrofit actions. It's pretty easy. You can learn more about Retrofit from here [doc 1](https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-your-hand-dirty-with-retrofit-2-a-type-safe-http-client-for-android-and-java-c546f88b3a51) [doc 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)